# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded While Submitting Map Reduce

Tags: hadoop

Getting below message while submitting map reduce. I started my map reduce program with  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m memory size.

Do anyone has the clue whats going on right now -

```
17/03/24 09:58:46 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Created HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 1160328 for svc_pffr on ha-hdfs:nameservice3
    17/03/24 09:58:46 ERROR hdfs.KeyProviderCache: Could not find uri with key [dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri] to create a keyProvider !!
    17/03/24 09:58:46 INFO security.TokenCache: Got dt for hdfs://nameservice3; Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: ha-hdfs:nameservice3, Ident: (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 1160328 for svc_pffr)
    17/03/24 09:58:46 ERROR hdfs.KeyProviderCache: Could not find uri with key [dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri] to create a keyProvider !!
    17/03/24 09:58:46 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
    17/03/24 09:58:47 ERROR hdfs.KeyProviderCache: Could not find uri with key [dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri] to create a keyProvider !!
    17/03/24 10:01:55 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /user/svc_pffr/.staging/job_1489708003568_5870
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.Token.<init>(Token.java:85)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.LocatedBlock.<init>(LocatedBlock.java:52)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:755)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convertLocatedBlock(PBHelper.java:1174)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1192)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1436)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1445)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:549)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getListing(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:1893)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$15.<init>(DistributedFileSystem.java:742)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listLocatedStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:731)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:1664)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:300)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:59)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:589)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:606)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:490)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
```

Comment: Actually in my case - I am getting 6000 input paths and my map-reduce program is going to create minimum 6000 mappers and hence I am getting out of memory exception while submitting. Is there any good approach to fix this type of issue .

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the client heap size.

Can you try : -  export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="$HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS -Xmx1g".

Then start your hadoop execution without the **XX:MaxPermSize=128m**

You can check this link also .. http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/cloudera-hadoop-mapreduce-job-GC-overhead-limit-exceeded-error/td-p/14754

Comment: Actually in my case - I am getting 6000 input paths and my map-reduce program is going to create minimum 6000 mappers and hence I am getting out of memory exception while submitting. Do you have any alternate solution regarding this. What should be the approach to fix this.

Comment: Can you try to implement the Combine File Input Format and specify a larger split size. For reference :-  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0-alpha2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html

Comment: Actually I cant use Combine File Input as we have some restrictions. Is there any other alternate option.

Comment: If you cannot use CombineFileInputFormat, you can try a work around.
You can reduce the amount of files, lets say you have 6000 files, try to hit in between 1000-2000 files per run. 
Write a small loop to execute before the driver multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exception, I just formatted my hdfs because it was saturated!

```
$ hadoop namenode -format
```

Pay attention please: If you format your hdfs you will lose all the meta-data related to data-nodes So all the information on the datanodes will be lost!

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my case - I am getting 6000 input paths and my map-reduce program is going to create minimum 6000 mappers and hence I am getting out of memory exception while submitting. Is there any good approach to fix this type of issue .

Answer (score 0):

I know this sound weird, but I had the same error and I have found the cause. For me, it was the `firehose_non_java_memory_bytes` inside `Cloudera Management Service` that was set too high.

I don't know wether this will solve your issue, bit it may be worth to try.