# GC overhead limit exceeded for Map Reduce, when Input files number is large

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have written MR job, which will process more than 5800 input files.
When I started it, it was failling with "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded".
Below is the exception stack-trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.Token.<init>(Token.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.LocatedBlock.<init>(LocatedBlock.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:755)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convertLocatedBlock(PBHelper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:549)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getListing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:1893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$15.<init>(DistributedFileSystem.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listLocatedStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:1664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
```

Is there any limit on number of input files for Map-Reduce. 
I have tried to run it with 1.2 GB memory alos

Comment: where did you increase the memory? The OOM happens on submission, so it is the client application that needs more heap.

Comment: I don't know why people are down voting it

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shown us any code, it is only possible to talk in generalities.

This problem is not caused by any Hadoop specific limit on the *number* of files.  It is possible that it is due to the aggregate size of the files ... after their contents have been read and loaded into the heap.  But not necessarily.

What is actually happening here is that you have (almost) filled the heap, and the JVM has decided that you are spending too much time garbage collecting.

Broadly speaking, there are three possible causes for this kind of problem:

1. The heap is too small for the size of problem you are trying to solve.
2. Your application is making inefficient use of memory.
3. Your application has a memory leak.

In your case, I would first assume that it is problem 1.  I would try with a lot fewer files and/or try using a (much) larger heap.  If either of these solves the problem, you are done (for now), though obviously this is going to put a bound on the size of problem that you can handle.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then you are going to treat this as if you were looking for a memory leak; i.e. figure out why the application uses so much (too much) memory.

I would note that 1.2Gb is not a particularly large heap.

Comment: I can help a bit judging from the stacktrace, it is indeed the listing of the files that is the problem. That's a common problem for MapReduce jobs that have too many little files and devs starting big jobs from their laptops with Java default heap sizes.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut - We can't conclude that.  The only thing we can safely conclude is that the problem (GC overhead limit) was *detected* while listing files.  In fact the OP tells us that there are 5,800 input files ... which tends to suggest that listing the files is not the problem.  Now ... maybe the OP is wrong about that.  However we have no clear evidence of that.

Comment: Sorry, I can not share code, As its Banks' project code base. Job Initialization class(Child class of Configured and Tool Class), which get Input paths in CSV file, and iterate over it and call  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputPath));  for all provided Path. I have tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997177/getting-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-while-submitting/43009239#43009239.

Comment: Like I said.  If you don't / can't show us the code, I / we can only talk generalities.  Of course, if you really needed help you could construct an MCVE which demonstrates the problem ... with all sensitive code removed / replaced.

Comment: @StephenC I understood those are 5.8k directories (which is what `getListing` gives you). Those can be many more files, so 5.8k is the multiplier rather than the actual number.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut - Well, I understood *"more than 5800 input files"* to refer to ... files.